# _itemFailedToPlayToEnd issue in iOS 7 while playing the recorded video using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to make an app for record video and play that video.
Sometimes video is playing nicely but some times it gives the error. 
I am using MPMoviePlayerController Class

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
  kind = 1;
  new = 2;
  old = 0;
}"
```

Please help friends. What should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL from which you play the video. When URL is wrong then this error will occur.